# Converting a text file into a multi dimensional list(Python3)

Tags: python-3.4

So I have a text file in this format
1, 23, 34343, 43
2, 34, 324 ,234
etc.
I want to convert it into a list in the same format, but when i do it comes in this format 1, 23, 34, 343,43,2, 34, 324 ,234(all in one line please)(I'm using python 3)

crimefile = open(fileName, 'r')
yourResult = [line.split(',') for line in crimefile.readlines()]

Comment: Please share your current code.

Comment: I just did that so please check again!